# I can not see my relative layout as before

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

It might be an easy question, but I have not found the answer after many hours.
How can I get back from the first picture to the second one?
I didn't want to change from relative to constraint layout, but I don't know how to get back. What I want to see again is picture 2.

**Constraint Layout:**

[image]

**Relative Layout:**

[image]

Comment: Put some code here. To understand ur question

Comment: You need to describe the design of your app - there is a multitude of ways you could've wanted this implemented and nobody will guess what is the one you're aiming for. Also, please embed the pictures in the question.

Comment: post your xml file

Comment: go your xml and change <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout> to relative layout

Comment: `CTRL+Z`? Source control systems?(GIT, SVN, etc)

Comment: Thanks to Vadivel, easy as expected, but I was looking for the solution at the wrong place. Designer = bad, Code = great!